# Xcode swift iOS project gives "usr/bin/python no such file or directory" error when try to build project

Tags: python, ios, swift, xcode, macos

I am experiencing the problem after the macOS 12.3 Monterey update. I get the following error when I want to run the project. There is a code looking for **"/usr/bin/python"** in the project, but I couldn't find which part of code/framework/script etc. is looking for that path in my project. There is no problem in the path "usr/local/bin/python", but my project gives the error that I cannot find the path to "usr/bin/python". When I looked there, **"/usr/bin/python3"** exist. Unfortunately, since it is the system folder, I cannot make any changes(add or remove files or links) in that folder.[image]

Comment: Also, please *don't* leave out the leading slash. It's relevant.

Comment: @ymeksur did you find a solution to the problem?

Comment: @KerimKhasbulatov no didn’t find any solution yet

Comment: @Sören yes i tried with leading slash but no success

Comment: That wasn't a suggestion. I was telling you that your question doesn't match your screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to install python2. This can be done according to the [guide](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/kb/python-2-monterey/)

Then it is necessary in the file

`{PATH_TO_PROJECT}/scripts/licenses/importLicensePods.py`

replace the first line with `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/local/python`